# How to Unchecked the Checkbox in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to unchecked the checkbox in my PHP edit page. I want those should be checked which value is 1 in database and those should be unchecked which value is zero(0) in Database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="edituser" value="<?php  if ($row['editusers']==1) $checked="checked";?>"> Edit Users</input>
```

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST['edituser'])) { $_POST['edituser'] = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="edituser" value="some value" checked="<?php echo (bool)$checked_value ?>"/> 
//$checked_value is grabbed from database either 0 or 1
```

If the value is checked the checkbox will be checked else unchecked.

Comment: it will checked every time the checkbox even if the value is 0 in table <input type="checkbox" name="adduser" value=1" checked=<?php  echo $row['addusers'];?>"  >

Comment: I've updated the answer. use `(bool)$value` to get boolean value 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="adduser" value=<?php echo $row['adduser'] ?> <?php echo ($row['adduser'] === 1) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />